# Adding <f:debug> to a TYPO3 Template affects behaviour of site

Tags: html, templates, typo3, extbase

I have been trying to implement a pdf-viewer in a template in Typo3. This works perfectly while there is a <f:debug></f:debug> embedded inside the template. However, if i remove this debug element, the pdf doesn't start rendering.

I noticed that TYPO3 moves everything from the  part of the html to the body and puts only a  element with the styles for the debug element if it is present. Otherwise the ,  etc. elements are put here by TYPO3. I don't know if these are mere side effects or whether this is related to my problem.

Why does adding <f:debug></f:debug> affects the structure of the output html so drastically and is there any summary of everthing that it changes? Is there a simple method to copy these effects without a debug element?

I tried replicating the effects from adding a debug element to the template, like moving all assets to the body, however this was unsuccsessful.

Comment: sometimes a `<f:debug>` loads data which might not load by default because of lazy loading. it seams your PDF generation does not trigger lazy loading. You might get better results if you use some data before the pdf-generation. You might output a title or just use a value in a condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a good hint in Slack about the same issue - the idea is that the debug output puts the browser in quirks mode and therefore "forgives" the code of deprecated methods, for example. I think that's a good starting point.

Comment: To elaborate on this: f:debug adds code before the first `<!doctype html>` section (that defines "modern" HTML usually). This extra output of f:debug (with inline styles and the like) will be interpreted by the browser first, not recognizing this doctype (because not in the first line) and thus trigger the quirks mode. So the same problem should occur for you with the JS lib, if you just omit the doctype part. To solve it you will need to actually adapt your JS lib to work with non-quirks mode browser settings.

Comment: (That the code is included in "head" or modifies that is only something you see in the browser inspector - the actual HTML output does not modify your head. It's just that the browser tries to make the best of a bad HTML formatting situation and internally re-arranges the extra HTML output at the top of the page)